# where am i doing the mistake?

Tags: python, if-statement

Write a simple program that demonstrates a fruitful function.

Take two integers num1 and num2 as input from the user using input() function. Define a function largestintwo() it has two parameters a and b. Take two integer inputs num1 and num2 from the user calculate the largest of the given two inputs. Print the result as shown in the example.

Sample Input and Output:
num1: 260
num2: 300
largest: 300

```
def largestintwo(a,b):
    a=n1
    b=n2
    if a>b:
        return b
    else:
        return b
n1=int(input('num1: '))
n2=int(input('num2: '))
result =lagestintwo(n1,n2)
print('largest:',result)
```

Comment: the function returns always b

Comment: Both paths return b. One of them should return a.

Comment: also, the assignments `a=n1` and `b=n2` inside the function are pointless.

Comment: The function already exists; it is called `max()`

Comment: The answer of thatotherguy is correct. May I suggest to use something like VS Code. The missing R which is metioned in the answer of thatotherguy is shown in VS Code as an alert and if you debug with VS code this will be returned as an error.

In the debugmode you will find an overview of variables. With that screen you could find the error of twice returning b.

But hey! We are here to learn right! Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

There are three separate errors, each commented below:

```
def largestintwo(a,b):
    # a and b are already being passed as parameters
    # so you don't need to populate them with n1/n2.
    # a=n1
    # b=n2
    if a>b:
        # This has to return a, not b
        return a
    else:
        return b
n1=int(input('num1: '))
n2=int(input('num2: '))
# This name was missing the 'r'
result =largestintwo(n1,n2)
print('largest:',result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comment the issue here is that the function returns always b.

I sugest the following modifications:

```py
def largestintwo(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

Assign `a` and `b` is not useful and the return statement has been adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

You are only ever returning b, even when a > b.

Your code should look something like this:

```
def largestintwo(a,b):
    a=n1
    b=n2
    if a>b:
        return a
    else:
        return b

n1=int(input('num1: '))
n2=int(input('num2: '))
result = largestintwo(n1,n2)
print('largest:',result)
```

With this change, your code should run properly.

Comment: That's not the only problem, and typos should simply be closed as unreproducible rather than answered. (You will need slightly more reputation on this site to leave a comment, but work on proper answers and you'll get there.)